# PDO Statement inserts integers for string values in prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo

My prepared statement is defined as a method of a generic mysql class. Inserts using this method which insert into a different table work fine. Inserts into a specific table replace all my interpolated values with integers. Prepared statement and query look fine. 
It looks like the integers inserted are interpolated from the "category_id" field.

The statement preparation:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post_data (`headline`, `body`,`online`,`category_id`,`post_date`)
        VALUES (:headline, :body, :online, :categoryId, NOW())";
$bindValues = array('headline' => (string) $headline
, 'body' => (string) $body
, 'online' => (int) $online
, 'categoryId' => (int) $categoryId);
$mysql->insert($sql, $bindValues);
```

The $mysql->insert method (which works for another table but not the above query:

```
public function insert($sql, array $bindValues) {
$stmt = $this->pdoConn->prepare($sql);
foreach ($bindValues as $name => $value) {
    $type = PDOBindings::getType($value);
    //see below for PDOBindings::getType()
    $stmt->bindParam($name, $value, $type);
}
try {
     $this->pdoConn->beginTransaction();
     $stmt->execute();
     $this->lastInserted = $this->pdoConn->lastInsertId();
     $this->pdoConn->commit();
} catch(Execption $e) {
     $this->pdoConn->rollback();
     return $e->getMessage();
}
return ($this->lastInserted > 0) ? $this->lastInserted : null;
```

The PDOBindings::getType() static method is fairly straightforward:

```
public static function getType($bindValue) {
    $itsType = gettype($bindValue);
    switch ($itsType) {
        case "string":
            return PDO::PARAM_STR;
        break;
        case "integer":
            return PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
        case "boolean":
            return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
        default :
        return PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}
```

An insert of:

```
INSERT INTO post_data (`headline`, `body`,`online`,`category_id`,`post_date`)
VALUES (:headline, :body, :online, :categoryId, NOW())
```

with the following:

```
$bindValues = array('headline' => (string) "This is the headline"
       , 'body' => (string) "This is the body field to be inserted"
       , 'online' => (int) 0
       , 'categoryId' => (int) 2);
```

Inserts the following row:

```
id  headline    body    online  category_id     post_date

7   2           2   2   2           2013-11-03 08:34:49
```

Note that the categoryId had the value of 2.

Stepping through the query with Xdebug does not indicate any issues with the data being set incorrectly.

It's difficult to debug as I cannot step into the PDO libraries themselves to determine where it's overriding the interpolations.

A quick note on the schemas. headline is a varchar, body is text, online is tinyint and category_id is a medium int.

Also, remember that this insert works just fine for another table.

Here's what didn't work:

Re-arranging the order of the insert items, and bindings arrays.

Removing date-time field. (throws exception.)

What works is inserting directly into rows, or using old-school mysql query building.

Additionally, this should ideally be a different question but PDO also seems not to be recognizing exception handlers:

```
$this->pdoConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Doesn't throw exceptions in the above try block. execution just fails.

Comment: Wow. it took you time.

Comment: The question kept getting rejected because of code formatting. You can't just cut-and-paste your code. I wish they'd change that feature to make it easier for us to just paste code here.

Comment: Just one side note. Most of your code is quite useless. You wrote a lot of code and got it worse than with raw PDO

Comment: Oh hey thanks! So was your "answer" telling me to debug Compiled Binary Code!! You have no idea the context or what the usage is for this useless code, so please, use some of your "common senses" and keep it to yourself.

Comment: I know enough programming to judge the code I see.

Comment: You offer an insulting comment on what you think is useless, yet offer no insight as to what you deem incorrect. Then you qualify your judgment by 'knowing enough programming.' You downvote my question for some unforseen reason, based on your judgment, offer a completely useless answer and then comment a critique of my code. Does that help answer anything? I don't care what your opinion is. I don't have room for a-holes like you either. Go and troll somebody else. Abuse should not be tolerated on this forum.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the only insulting comment here is your latter one. I don't mind it, though. Just to fix the fact.

Comment: Here is a use case taken directly from php.net that is doing what I'm doing. [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#104939) Note the warn against bindParams passing by reference.

Comment: Oh, anyone can add any rubbish directly on php.net in comments section. So, one have to be very cautious about the code taken from there. As a matter of fact, this binding code is totally useless. You will get **exactly** the same result if use raw PDO: `$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($bindValues);` just try it and see. Especially because transaction for a single query is essentially useless as well. Your code adds nothing to raw PDO but extra complexity and errors.

Comment: The only tiny chance for for such a manual binding being useful - is notorious LIMIT clause. You can't use default PDO::PARAM_STR in LIMIT clause and that's sad. But affects only emulation mode. So, if you set emulation mode to false, even this little inconvenience won't ever bother you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40542/discussion-between-eggmatters-and-your-common-sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `bindParam` binds the parameters by reference. You're binding all your parameters to the same variable `$value`. So when you execute the prepared statement, it will use the last value of this variable for all the parameters. That's why it's inserting `2` in every column.

Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` and I think it should solve your problem. Or get rid of your loop that calls `bindParam` entirely, and just pass `$bindValues` to `execute()`.

Comment: Using bindValue worked like a charm. The explanation of bindParam passing by reference makes perfect sense. It looks like it inserted correctly using 'bindValue'. This also explains why the subsequent GET is failing. This kills several birds with one stone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No need to step into PDO libraries themselves (although you can, as it's open source) - it doesn't override the interpolations.

It's your code does that. So, you have to continue with debugging.

Comment: Are not the PDO libraries binaries? I could be wrong. The array values are generated as they should be. The calls to $stmt->bindParam($name, $value, $type); are passing in the proper expected values. (i.e. $stmt->bindParams('headline','This is a headline', PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Every binary compiled from source code. Anyway, Barmar already spotted it.